# Windows 7 Firewall stopped working after I changed permissions for the registry key SharedAccess

Tags: windows, windows-7, permissions, firewall

Today I've changed permissions for the registry key `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess` (under which FirewallRules are stored) removing *"Everyone"* and *"Users"* in order to restrict access to the key from the account of the standard user.

When I restarted the laptop I see that Windows Firewall doesn't work at all and when I try to open its *"Advanced settings"* I see the error on the screenshot

[image]

Is it possible to fix the problem without re-installing Windows?

Comment: Why can't you redo the deleted permissions?

Comment: @harrymc How? I don't remember them

Answer (score 1):

To redo the permissions of `SharedAccess`, from my Windows 10 :

- `users` has only the Read permissions
- `everyone` is not present at all, and probably only
  required for access from the local network.
  If you would like to restore it, give it also the Read permission.

Comment: It's Windows 7, as specified in the title and the tag

Comment: It shouldn't be much different and can serve as a starting point.

Comment: The problem is, I removed "Everyone" at all from the key SharedAccess, not just permissions for it

Comment: No problem - use the Add button, type `everyone`, click Check Names, click OK, click Read (below), click OK.

Comment: I did as you described and restarted computer, but that didn't help. I also tried all 4 solutions described by the [link](https://www.minitool.com/news/the-ox6d9-error-in-windows-defender-firewall-019.html), but still without success...

Comment: I'm not sure that the change to `SharedAccess` is responsible for all your troubles. If System Restore is enabled and you have a restore point from before the registry changes, then rollback to it. Otherwise, I think you should [Do a Repair Install to Fix Windows 7](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html). Take a backup before starting, and use a Windows 7 ISO of the same service-pack level as your computer.

Comment: Ok, I was forced to re-install Windows. One more question: the `MpsSvc` user name appeared in the `Permissions for FirewallPolicy` window. What does it mean?

Comment: The [Networking-MPSSVC-Svc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/networking-mpssvc-svc) service component is part of Windows Firewall.